# How to shift lines of code in XCode

Tags: xcode, macos, editor

Is there any way in XCode to shift Code up or down with the keyboard? In Notepad++ for instance this was done by Ctrl-Shift-Up or Down and it shifted the current line.

Am I just blind or is this feature just absent?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>

Have a look in the Xcode preferences under Key bindings for others.

If you are looking for even more  have a look at Colin Wheeler's [Xcode 4 Keyboard Shortcuts](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2011/03/xcode-4-keyboard-shortcuts-now.html)

Comment: Thank you so much. Really saved some nerves!

Comment: Too bad that key combination doesn't work on swedish keyboard =(

Comment: @Codler Why? don't you have square brackets on Swedish Keyboards? I use a British Keyboard with the Dvorak layout, the key combination still works.

Comment: we have, but square brackets are on ALT+8, so it isn't possible.

Comment: @Codler Have you thought of changing the keybinding then? It's quite easy to do from the Xcode preferences under Key Bindings.

Comment: Yes, I changed to ALT+CMD+UP and ALT+CMD+DOWN